# Loading JSON data from an API using Retrofit and populating it in Recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

Everything seems to be working fine when debugging , im getting the JSON response as i expected but it doesn't get populated to my recyclerview, giving

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

any information how can i fix this ?

This is how my API Looks like

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name_en": "Project Management",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name_en": "Quality Management",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name_en": "IT Service Management",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name_en": "IT Security",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name_en": "IT Audit",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name_en": "Operating Systems",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name_en": "Networks",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name_en": "Virtualization and Cloud",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name_en": "Web App and Programming",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name_en": "Design an Special Effects",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name_en": "Business Productivity Tools",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name_en": "Certified Business Professional",
            "name_ar": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name_en": "Diploma Courses",
            "name_ar": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

JSONResponse Class

```
public class JSONResponse {

    private CategoryModel[] list;

    public CategoryModel[] getCategories() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Request Interface

```
public interface RequestInterface {

    @GET("projects/newhorizons/api/categories")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

ModelClass

```
public class CategoryModel {
    private int id;
    private String name_en;
    private String name_ar;
    private String categoryImage;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName_en() {
        return name_en;
    }

    public String getName_ar() {
        return name_ar;
    }

    public String getCategoryImage() {
        return categoryImage;
    }
}
```

AdapterClass

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryView> {

    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels;

    public CategoryAdapter(ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels) {
        this.categoryModels = categoryModels;

}

    @Override
    public CategoryView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_list_item,parent,false);
        return new CategoryView(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryView holder, int position) {

        //holder.categoryImage.setImageResource(categoryModels.get(position).getCategoryImage());
        holder.categoryName.setText(categoryModels.get(position).getName_en());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModels.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView categoriesView;
    private ArrayList<CategoryModel> courseCategories;
    private CategoryAdapter myCategoryAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        initViews();

        CategoryItemDecoration decoration= new CategoryItemDecoration(this,R.dimen.item_offset);
        categoriesView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);



    }

    private void initViews(){

        loadJSON();

        categoriesView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.categories_grid);
        categoriesView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    private void loadJSON(){
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://combal.net")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = requestInterface.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();

                //relieve the categories here
                JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
                courseCategories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getCategories()));
                myCategoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(courseCategories);
                categoriesView.setAdapter(myCategoryAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here is my CategoryView Class

```
public class CategoryView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       public ImageView categoryImage;
       public TextView categoryName;

public CategoryView(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoryImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        }
}
```

Comment: Where does the exception get thrown? (stack trace, or at least what line)

Comment: it says **E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout ,**  for information when debugging actually i get the response from the API , the problem is i cant show "name_en" in the textView

Comment: where u defined CategoryView  class in your adapter

Comment: I guess it's not an exception, but just an "Error" log message.

Comment: @Onkar i have updated uploaded my CategoryView Class Which just have references to my image view and text view **note that im not using the image view currently**

Comment: @LarsH i am not getting any exceptions which is making it harder to catch

Comment: Is the `JSON` being parsed correctly?

Comment: @KNeerajLal what do you mean by correctly ?

Comment: @KareemEl-Bayaa Means is there data in `courseCategories` before setting the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Your code calling adapter in onResponse() method which runs on backround thread.
UI elements only run on main thread i.e UIThread, here you need call adapter on main thread i.e use runOnUIThread(Runnable r) method.

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, 
        Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            int statusCode = response.code();

            //relieve the categories here
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            courseCategories = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getCategories()));

          MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                  myCategoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(courseCategories);
            categoriesView.setAdapter(myCategoryAdapter);

        }
    });
        }
```

Comment: Can you clarify more please ?

Comment: Same issue still there ... didn't help

Comment: i seen your code deeply ..  initialise Reclyerview before calling loadJSON() method move that two line before loadJSON() ..  try .